# Retry loop position after specified time

Tags: python, python-2.7, timeout, signals, subprocess

Is there a way to restart part of a loop if it hasn't completed after a specified time that is subprocess-friendly?

I have a script, say `main.py` that spawns X instances of other worker scripts using `subprocess.Popen()`. Each "worker" is essentially checking it's respective queue hosted on Azure for jobs (each worker and queue providing different functions and jobs).

The problem is the `andy` worker (`andy.py`) tends to sometimes get hung at a certain part of a `while` loop that is calling a function. I've tried using SIGALRM to interrupt what it's doing, which raises an exception that simply calls `pass`. The `signal.alarm()` aborts it's attempt, which in turn cause it to just retry searching the date since it's in the `while` loop.

The problem is, it SEEMS like when an alarm is triggered in, it will sometimes also affect a completely different subprocess that is running and interrupt what it was doing as well. All I would like is if the function takes more than X seconds to complete, try to run the function again.

Here is an example of what the code looks like (granted, the functions have been replaced with code that is runable for anyone, and i've removed all functionality to run workers other than `andy`):

**main.py**

```
import subprocess as sp
import sys
import time
import datetime
import thread


max_workers = {'andy': 10}


def check():
    workers = {'andy': {}}

    while True:
        for worker, instances in workers.items():
            while len(instances) < max_workers[worker]:
                process = sp.Popen(['python', 'workers/%s.py' % worker], shell=False)
                workers[worker][process] = process.pid
        for worker, instances in workers.items():
            for process, pid in instances.items():
                if process.poll() is not None:
                    del workers[worker][process]


def time_check():
    global max_workers
    start = datetime.time(hour=07, minute=05)
    end = datetime.time(hour=23, minute=00)
    while 1:
        now = datetime.datetime.now().time().replace(second=0, microsecond=0)
        if now == start:
            time.sleep(60)
            max_workers['andy'] = 7
        elif now == end:
            time.sleep(60)
            max_workers['andy'] = 0
        else:
            time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    while 1:
        try:
            thread.start_new_thread(check, ())
            thread.start_new_thread(time_check, ())
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            sys.exit(0)
```

**andy.py**

```
import datetime
import otas
import json
import time
import signal


def alarm_handler():
    pass


def start():

    resort_ids = 'Los Angeles', 'New York', 'Chicago', 'Miami'
    start_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    end_date = start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=10)
    ota = otas.Expedia(headless=False)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, alarm_handler)
    for resort_id in resort_ids:
        search_date = start_date
        while search_date < end_date:
            signal.alarm(15)
            try:
                data = ota.search_by_date(resort=resort_id, checkin=search_date)
            except:
                pass
            else:
                try:
                    print data
                except TypeError:
                    pass
                search_date += datetime.timedelta(days=1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
```

**otas.py**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import datetime


class Expedia:
    def __init__(self, headless=True):
        if headless is True:
            self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
        else:
            self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()


    def search_by_date(self, resort, checkin, flexibility=4, nights=3):
        driver = self.driver
        try:
            driver.get(
                'http://www.expedia.com/Hotel-Search?#&destination={0}&startDate={1}&endDate={2}'.format(
                    resort, checkin.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"), (checkin + datetime.timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
                )
            )
            return driver.page_source
        except Exception, e:
            return e
```

EDIT4: Rewrote question and code to be user-reproducable, and be more clear.

Comment: Do you still have trouble if you send `sigalrm` from the process spawning script (i.e. my example below).

Comment: there are multiple issues in your question that looks like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/137096). Describe what you are trying to do because to kill a subprocess, you don't need `SIGALRM` just call `process.kill()` after the deadline in *the parent*. [Create a minimal example that demonstrates your issue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) -- don't include `strftime()`, `log.error()` unless the issue disappears without these calls.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I modified the code above to not include `log.error()` or `strftime()`, and to try to clarify what i'm doing. I'm not trying to kill the process. The `ota.search_by_date()` is a function that is imported in 'andy.py' with `import ota`. It is supposed to loop through dates until it gets to `end_date`. Each date runs the imported function to return a hotel's availability on the `search_date` provided.

Comment: @crookedleaf: read the 2nd link in my last comment, try to create a *complete* code example

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian just edited the post to include as complete (yet stripped of logging, date formatting, etc.) of a code sample as i can provide.

Comment: @crookedleaf: the goal is so that others can run your code – `otas`, `cloud` prevent that. The code should be *both* complete and minimal.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian the problem is they are modules that require login credentials and log into websites containing extremely sensitive data, which i unfortunately can not provide.

Comment: @crookedleaf: if you can't reproduce the problem without these modules how do you expects others to help you?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I know, and I completely understand. I also know there isn't anything I can realistically do to the 3rd party modules to get the functions to be more reliable, as i'm not allowed to edit the code. That is why, instead, i'm just trying to find a way to accomplish what I was asking regardless of what function is being used. I'm not trying to fix whatever is causing the code to hang, i'm just trying to get it to stop what it's doing and retry if it does hang. `signal.alarm()` has been used before, but as said, it unfortunately seems to affect other concurrently running subprocesses

Comment: @crookedleaf: the point is: sending SIGALRM won't terminate sibling processes. I've read your code: it can't possibly work -- it is unrelated to SIGALRM -- the code tries to start infinite number child processes -- OS may start killing random processes at that point.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian It sounded to me like he wanted to use SIGALRM to interrupt the process when it hangs not to kill it- I'm not really sure what the problem is ~ I agree with your comment that the question should be fixed to be issue specific though - debugging other people's entire routines isn't really the point of stackoverflow imho; so I'm down-voting until the question is edited into a more presentable form.

Comment: @user3467349 Correct, i'm not trying to kill the process. As my question states, i'm trying to figure out how to retry where the loop is at if it does get hung... not to figure out and fix what is causing it to hang since it is an array of different problems ranging from the page not loading, the page timing out, the webdriver crashing, a proxy server failure, etc., and all these are issues in the 3rd party library that doesn't have good error handling and i can't modify it's code. Outside of the first sentence and my "EDIT2", i'm not sure how to edit the question into a more presentable form.

Comment: @crookedleaf reduce the question to simply your inability to interrupt and restart a subprocess - you don't need a bunch of data fetching and processing code for that `time.sleep(60); print('foo')` or something of the like should be quite enough. It should ideally be an error or issue other people can reproduce.

Comment: @user3467349 I have rewritten the question and code. The code should now be reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your process specific code - but here is what I tried and it seems to work:

`sp_worker.py`

```
import time
import signal
try:
    time.sleep(60)
    print("finished")
except: 
    print("got interupted")
```

`__main__`

```
import subprocess as sp
import signal
proc1 = sp.Popen(['python', 'sp_worker.py'], stdout=sp.PIPE) 
proc2 = sp.Popen(['python', 'sp_worker.py'], stdout=sp.PIPE)
proc1.send_signal(signal.SIGALRM)
proc1.communicate() 
(b'got interupted\n', None)
proc2.communicate() #(blocks)
```

Comment: I don't want to kill the entire process. Essentially, `main.py` starts un 10 instances of `andy.py` via `subprocess.Popen()`. Each `andy.py` gets a message from a queue for a different hotel, and searches a website for that hotel's availability. The `ota.search_by_date()` is a function that is imported in 'andy.py' with `import ota`. It is supposed to loop through dates until it gets to `end_date`, then parse and save the data to a unique file. Each date runs the imported function to return a hotel's availability on the `search_date` provided, but sometimes gets hung on a date.

Comment: That's what I'm saying, send_signal to interupt the subprocess from the main process, catch the signal in an `except` and restart the data read or whatever you need to do. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues in your code. Here's a fragment that starts infinite number of threads.

```
#XXX BROKEN, DO NOT DO IT
while 1:
    try:
        thread.start_new_thread(check, ())
        thread.start_new_thread(time_check, ())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit(0)
```

OS resources are finite. If memory is exhausted before other resources (each thread needs a stack); some OSes may start killing unrelated processes (OOM Killer).

Your intent is probably to run repeatedly two functions at the same time:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

pool = ThreadPool(2)
while True:
    try:
        r = pool.apply_async(check)
        pool.apply(time_check) # block until time_check() returns
        r.get() # block until check() returns
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
```

Wrap `check()`, `time_check()` functions to catch and log all exceptions.